# Why does exception::what not return a std::string

Tags: c++, exception

I was trying to come up with custom `std::exception` class and I got confused about how to properly implement `what()`.

For example, let's have

```
class int_error : std::exception
{
    int param;
public:
    int_error(int param)
        : param(param)
    {
    }

    char const* what() const override
    {
        // return "Error occurred while processing number " + param
        // How to return this?
    }
};
```

I can't use `std::string("text").c_str()` (that is destroyed before the function returns) and anything related to managing the lifetime manually (like `new char[]`) wouldn't work (would leak memory), since I can't ever delete it (because I can't even store the pointer anywhere, since `what` is `const`).

I am aware that I could prepare the error string in advance (constructor) and then just return it in `what`.

If `what` returned `std::string` instead, I wouldn't have this difficulty. Is this an oversight to the STL or am I missing something (I probably am).

Comment: Because constructing and copying a `std::string` can also throw an exception.   Throwing a second exception while copying an exception during stack unwinding would cause all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does exception::what not return a std::string

Because exceptions sometimes need to be used in contexts where dynamic allocation is not possible. Consider for example handling of the exception `std::bad_alloc`. `std::string` potentially requires dynamic allocation, and thus the API of `std::exception` cannot use it.

> I am aware that I could prepare the error string in advance (constructor) and then just return it in what.

This is indeed what you should do. Note however that storing a `std::string` member also has problems because it makes the copy constructor of the exception class potentially throwing.

Solution is to inherit from `std::runtime_error`. It has a constructor that accepts a string. It takes care of the hard part of storing the string without potential throws.

Answer (score 0):

KISS: make it a class buffer:

```
class int_error : std::exception
{
    int param;
    char mutable buffer[64];
public:
    int_error(int param)
        : param(param)
    {
    }

    char const* what() const override
    {
        // set buffer to "Error occurred while processing number " + param
        return buffer;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::runtime_error`. It is basically `std::exception` with a constructor that takes the string to be returned from `what`. The cppreference page on [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) also has some good hints why you don't want to use `std::string` for the message:

> Notes

> Because copying std::runtime_error is not permitted to throw exceptions, this message is typically stored internally as a separately-allocated reference-counted string. This is also why there is no constructor taking std::string&&: it would have to copy the content anyway.

"... not permitted to throw exceptions" is true as well for `std::exception`. You wouldn't want another exception to be thrown while the original one is still flying.